# carriage return in Access 2000

Tags: ms-access, return, chr

I have 2 Access databases, both are Access 2000 both are copies of each other. But when I copy text to the one table it enters correctly as displayed below.

```
1st line  
2nd Line  
3rd Line
```

When I enter the same data to the second table, it is displayed like this

```
1st line2nd Line3rd Line
```

I can copy the date from the table paste it in MSWord and copy it back and then it is displayed like I want it.

```
1st line
2nd Line
3rd Line
```

Why would the second table be displaying it all in one line and the other table display it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you editing data on a form? You can change the behavior of the "enter" key for each text box on a form. If you make the text box larger (say a few lines), then  you can in the property sheet for that text box, on the "other" tab, change the enter key behavior from "default" to 
New line in field.

It not clear if you can't use the enter key to start a new line, or if the issue is cut + paste? You also want to check the property sheet if the text box is set to rich text, or plain text (you find this setting on the property sheet for the text box - data tab).